# Ionic 1. Откуда взялся артефакт?

Tags: ionicframework

Начал работать с Ionic 1 и при после создания стандартного приложения появился этот артефакт.
В HTML его нет. (или я не нашел). Просмотрел все `:before` и `:after` - тоже пусто. Пропадает после изменения любого визуального стиля, но появляется сразу после нажатия на кнопку меню в хедере. Подскажите, пожалуйста, как убрать данное недоразумение. 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Что за "кнопка в хедере"? Есть предположение, что это пустое меню так рисуется.

Comment: Эта кнопка сдвигает контент в право и выдвигает меню.

Comment: А можете html и стили в этой области показать?

Comment: @hardsky, [вот](http://pastebin.com/z0JT8yW7)

Comment: Честно говоря, тоже не понятно.

Comment: Вот и я про то же. Но тем не менее, оно появляется на всех устройствах.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

в ionic есть класс:

```
.scroll-content {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  overflow: hidden;

  // Hide the top border if any
  margin-top: -1px;

  // Prevents any distortion of lines
  padding-top:1px;

  width: auto;
  height: auto;
}
```

Я изменил значение "margin-top" на -4px и "padding-top" на 4px - результат меня устроил (пробовал на разных устройствах - где-то достаточно 3px, где-то - 4px - видимо, погрешность округления 'px').